# Multiple editText read and set

Tags: android

I have facing problem while changing the edittext values,
I have 3 EditText Box which takes value in any one of the Edittext, and updates on other,
It takes only one character and gives vaules for the other as well,
It doesn't take the second character.
Calculating for 
1.Kilometer
2.meter
3.miles

In this case I'll enter my value in any edittext. need to read and update aswell without button.
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question and post relevant code.

Comment: post screenshot what your want with your code.

Comment: Please give me solution